# How to referesh a ReactJS application automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I built a small boat visualizer. I am using [AISHub APIs](https://www.aishub.net/api). After fetching data from the APIs I am able to obtain a `json` file with the vessels I am interested in and inject these vessels inside a table. The API allows to proceed for a new fetch after 1 minute as stated officially [in their documentation](https://www.aishub.net/api).
The user has to manually update the page pushing the refresh button on top left of the page to see the new updated table.

[image: map]

**The problem**: Is it possible to proceed with an automatic update every minute without the user manually refreshing the page?

In order to bypass the one minute problem I had to organize a caching process and in fact that works well. I can refresh without waiting one minute, but I have to do it manually.

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var axios = require('axios');
const NodeCache = require('node-cache');
const myCache = new NodeCache();

let hitCount = 0;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/hello', async function(req, res, next) {

    const allData = myCache.get('allData');
if (!allData) {
    hitCount++;
    console.log(`hit ${hitCount} number of times`);
    const { data } = await axios.get(
        'http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=KEY&format=1&output=json&compress=0&latmin=11.42&latmax=58.20&lonmin=-134.09&lonmax=-52.62'
    );

    console.log(data + 'ERR');

    const [ metaData, ships ] = data;

    const shipsOfInterest = ships.filter(
        (ship) =>
            mmsiOfInterest.includes(ship.MMSI) ||
            shipNamesOfInterest.includes(ship.NAME) ||
            imoOfInterest.includes(ship.IMO)
    );

    myCache.set('allData', shipsOfInterest, 70);
    console.log(shipsOfInterest);

    res.send(shipsOfInterest);

    return;
}

console.log('this is the data:', allData);
res.send(allData);
});

module.exports = router;
```

**GoogleMap.js**

```
class BoatMap extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttonEnabled: true,
            buttonClickedAt: null,
            progress: 0,
            ships: [],
            type: 'All',
            shipTypes: [],
            activeShipTypes: [],
            logoMap: {}
        };
        this.updateRequest = this.updateRequest.bind(this);
        this.countDownInterval = null;
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.countDownInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (!this.state.buttonClickedAt) return;
            const date = new Date();
            const diff = Math.floor((date.getTime() - this.state.buttonClickedAt.getTime()) / 1000);

            if (diff < 90) {
                this.setState({
                    progress: diff,
                    buttonEnabled: false
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    progress: 0,
                    buttonClickedAt: null,
                    buttonEnabled: true
                });
            }
        }, 500);
        await this.updateRequest();

        const shipTypeResults = await Client.getEntries({
            content_type: 'competitors'
        });

        console.log(shipTypeResults);
        const shipTypes = shipTypeResults.items.map((data) => data.fields);

        const logoMap = shipTypes.reduce((acc, type) => {
            return {
                ...acc,
                [type.name]: type.images.fields.file.url
            };
        }, {});
        console.log({ shipTypes });
        this.setState({
            logoMap
        });
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.type !== prevState.type) {
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.countdownInterval);
    }

    async updateRequest() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3001/hello';
        console.log(url);
        const fetchingData = await fetch(url);
        const ships = await fetchingData.json();

        console.log(ships);

        this.setState({
            buttonEnabled: false,
            buttonClickedAt: new Date(),
            progress: 0,
            ships
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ buttonEnabled: true });
        });
    }


render() {
    return (
        <div className="google-map">
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'KEY' }}
                center={{
                    lat: this.props.activeShip ? this.props.activeShip.latitude : 42.4,
                    lng: this.props.activeShip ? this.props.activeShip.longitude : -71.1
                }}
                zoom={8}
            >
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have been doing a lot of research on how to automatically proceed with a refresh of the page without the user doing it manually. 
Thank for pointing to the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: This might be duplicate of this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354295/how-to-make-ajax-call-auto-refresh-in-react-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand the question. What is the mapping platform? Ideally you would not refresh the page at all. You would use state to refresh the map contents with a new ajax call every 60 seconds.

If you do just want to reload every 60 seconds then the below will work.

```
setTimeout(function () { 
      location.reload();
    }, 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for reading the question. I am using `google-map` API. Could you please integrate your code with my code so that I can understand where to put that function please?

Comment: Your code for the frontend is not posted. Only the node code?

Comment: Ok, I just updated the question with the frontend part

Comment: I don't think forcing the page to reload on a timer is a great idea from a user experience point of view, but this statement is a better approach and behavior natively supported by React: "Ideally you would not refresh the page at all. You would use state to refresh the map contents"

Comment: @KevinHooke, thanks for reading the question. Yes and that is the reason why I am getting rid of the buttons and have the timer to take care of that. But I don't know how to do that, that is why I was asking to integrate the timer with my code if that's possible.

Comment: If you use the setTimeout() example from @ReeceCasey to call the code that calls your endpoint to retrieve the data and the updated data is stored to your this.state, the components will redraw themselves to display the updated state

Comment: Ok from the map code you have posted there is some logic that happens after mount. Within this logic your fetch happens. Can you not just do this on an interval? If you test wrapping `updateRequest()` in a set interval you will see your http fetches reoccuring which you can then update state with, like you are now

Comment: Sorry @KevinHooke just seen your above. Yes although one thing to note it would be set interval not timeout if keeping the same page like we are suggesting

Comment: Thank you for reading and the suggestions. However I still did not understand where `setTimeout()` propsed by @ReeceCasey should be positioned. Could you please integrate your answer with the code provided? I am a bit confused on where to put insert the function.